# Google Apps Script - XML Parsing Issues

Tags: google-apps-script, xml

I'm using the ZoomInfo PersonSearch API in Google Apps Script. Within the framework, I'm using UrlFetchApp and XmlService when dealing with the query and parsing.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query);
var xml = response.getContentText();
var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
```

When I attempt to parse the response, I am informed that there is no DTD, however, the header and root element is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<personSearchResponse xmlns="http://partnerapi.zoominfo.com/partnerapistatic/xsd/V4">
```

The root element, as displayed above, includes the necessary XSD to parse the file. Why isn't XmlService recognizing this declaration?

Answer (score 1):

In case if XML-response contains [namespace](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp), you need to specify its value in the method. I see that your example has namespace: http://partnerapi.zoominfo.com/partnerapistatic/xsd/V4 and instead of getChild(name) you need to use the method: [getChild(name, namespace)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/).

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query);
var xml = response.getContentText();
var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
var root = document.getRootElement();
var namespace = XmlService.getNamespace('http://partnerapi.zoominfo.com/partnerapistatic/xsd/V4');
var someChild = root.getChild('ReplaceWithChildName', namespace);
```

Comment: the issue is with the parsing, not the access. when i call XmlService.parse(), the return is that there is no DTD specified. The parser cannot read the XML at all if it has no DTD, but as the XSD URL is defined within the root element, it should be able to.

Comment: Could you share the full response which you try to parse with XmlService?

Comment: the response is rather large, so you can find a sample response here: https://help.zoominfo.com/18440-partners/person-search

Comment: I also got in logs: "[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration" and I think that it means that the response doesn't have "!DOCTYPE note" and it actually doesn't have it (according to the link which you provided). In this case you can use:        
var document = XmlService.parse(xml); var descendants = document.getDescendants(); which gives you array of elements/values.